# Authorizate mongodb on compose using ssl

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl

I have a mongodb instance running at compose and I am trying to access it via pymongo.

I have the ssl private key and I am trying to connect using it with the following command:

```
url = 'composeServer:port'
user = 'user'
password = 'password'
ssl_file = './my-cert.pem'

client = MongoClient(url,username=user,password=password,ssl=True,ssl_ca_certs=ssl_file)
db = client['mydatabase']
db.collection_names()
```

This is issuing the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/database.py",
>   line 552, in collection_names
>       ReadPreference.PRIMARY) as (sock_info, slave_okay):   File "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in
>   **enter**
>       return next(self.gen)   File "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py",
>   line 904, in _socket_for_reads
>       with self._get_socket(read_preference) as sock_info:   File "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in
>   **enter**
>       return next(self.gen)   File "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py",
>   line 870, in _get_socket
>       with server.get_socket(self.**all_credentials) as sock_info:   File "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line
>   59, in __enter**
>       return next(self.gen)   File "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/server.py",
>   line 168, in get_socket
>       with self.pool.get_socket(all_credentials, checkout) as sock_info:   File "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line
>   59, in **enter**
>       return next(self.gen)   File "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py",
>   line 852, in get_socket
>       sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)   File "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py",
>   line 570, in check_auth
>       auth.authenticate(credentials, self)   File "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py",
>   line 486, in authenticate
>       auth_func(credentials, sock_info)   File "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py",
>   line 466, in _authenticate_default
>       return _authenticate_scram_sha1(credentials, sock_info)   File "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py",
>   line 209, in _authenticate_scram_sha1
>       res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)   File "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py",
>   line 477, in command
>       collation=collation)   File "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/network.py",
>   line 116, in command
>       parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)   File "/Users/israelzinc/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py",
>   line 210, in _check_command_response
>       raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response) pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.

When I try to connect to the server using normal mongo in the terminal, if I pass this certificate and the same user and password. It works, which means that there's no problem on those information.

I did exactly as the website told me to:

https://help.compose.com/v2.1/docs/connecting-to-mongodb#python-mongodb-and-compose

But still, no results.

Does anyone knows why?

Sincerely,
Israel

Comment: Those are options to the ["connection string"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) and NOT the [`MongoClient`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient) function. So the `username` and `password` and other "ssl" options need to be part of the "connection string" instead of additional arguments. Look at the documentation of both, which clearly states this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but how do I specify the certificate to the MongoClient then?

Comment: Thanks for not actually reading the documentation you were just linked to. Try taking a few minutes to actually read it. It's very clear

Comment: Didn't notice the link. Sorry.

Comment: Here's something a bit more direct: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html#mongodb-x509

Comment: Indeed you was correct and I put the whole information in the connection string and it worked. Many thanks for your help.